# Slew rate measuring

Tags: numpy, scipy, signal-processing, python-2.5

I have to measure slew rates in signals like the one in the image below. I need the slew rate of the part marked by the grey arrow.
[image: signal to process]

At the moment I smoothen the signal with a hann window to get rid of eventual noise and to flatten the peaks. Then I search (starting right) the 30% and 70% points and calculate the slew rate between this two points.
But my problem is, that the signal gets flattened after smoothing. Therefore the calculated slew rate is not as high as it should be. An if I reduce smoothing, then the peaks (you can see right side in the image) get higher and the 30% point is eventually found at the wrong position.

Is there a better/safer way to find the required slew rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know between what values your signal is transitioning, and your noise is not too large, you can simply compute the time differences between all crossings of 30% and all crossings of 70% and keep the smallest one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s100, s0 = 5, 0

signal = np.concatenate((np.ones((25,)) * s100,
                         s100 + (np.random.rand(25) - 0.5) * (s100-s0),
                         np.linspace(s100, s0, 25),
                         s0 + (np.random.rand(25) - 0.5) * (s100-s0),
                         np.ones((25,)) * s0))


# Interpolate to find crossings with 30% and 70% of signal
# The general linear interpolation formula between (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) is:
# y = y0 + (x-x0) * (y1-y0) / (x1-x0)
# to find the x at which the crossing with y happens:
# x = x0 + (y-y0) * (x1-x0) / (y1-y0)
# Because we are using indices as time, x1-x0 == 1, and if the crossing
# happens within the interval, then 0 <= x <= 1.
# The following code is just a vectorized version of the above
delta_s = np.diff(signal)
t30 = (s0 + (s100-s0)*.3 - signal[:-1]) / delta_s
idx30 = np.where((t30 > 0) & (t30 < 1))[0]
t30 = idx30 + t30[idx30]
t70 = (s0 + (s100-s0)*.7 - signal[:-1]) / delta_s
idx70 = np.where((t70 > 0) & (t70 < 1))[0]
t70 = idx70 + t70[idx70]

# compute all possible transition times, keep the smallest
idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(t30[:, None] - t70),
                       (len(t30), len(t70),))

print t30[idx[0]] - t70[idx[1]]
# 9.6

plt. plot(signal)
plt.plot(t30, [s0 + (s100-s0)*.3]*len(t30), 'go')
plt.plot(t30[idx[0]], [s0 + (s100-s0)*.3], 'o', mec='g', mfc='None', ms=10)
plt.plot(t70, [s0 + (s100-s0)*.7]*len(t70), 'ro')
plt.plot(t70[idx[1]], [s0 + (s100-s0)*.7], 'o', mec='r', mfc='None', ms=10 )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach. But at the moment I have trouble understanding your implementation. How do you get the time information? Your signal does not contain any time values.

Comment: @wewa I am using the position in the array as a proxy for time. If your signal is sampled with a constant time step `dt`, then all you need to do is multiply everything by that to have actual times.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought already. But to me it is not really clear how you calculate `t30`, `t70`, `idx30`, `idx70` and `idx`. Could you please comment this in your code?

Comment: @wewa I have added a lengthy comment right before that block, see if it makes sense.